# Getting error when stopping a Selenium session

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I'm running a selenium test by selenium grid, but when it executes `tearDownAfterClass()` method, this problem occurs:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Internal Server Error
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getCommandResponseAsString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:183)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.executeCommandOnServlet(HttpCommandProcessor.java:118)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:101)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.stop(HttpCommandProcessor.java:265)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.stop(DefaultSelenium.java:139)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.closeSeleniumSession(ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.java:33)
    at com.icil.at.as.testtool.Suppliernamelookupv03Test.tearDownAfterClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:525)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:202)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:34)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:351)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$CountDownLatchedRunnable.run(ThreadUtil.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

In my test script, this method is like this:

```
    @AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    closeSeleniumSession();
}
```

Someone suggested to use selenium.cloce() and this error disappeared. But in my script, it uses Selenium grid. And in my script, it's just this one method that failed, the others are successful.

Can someone help me check this and tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
what about this one?